# Filtrar json en firebase

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos, firebase

[image: Estructura de base de datos]

Tengo el objeto places que contiene ado y mall que también con objetos.

Lo que quiero hacer traer la información de ado solamente

```
let refFirebase = `countries/mexico/state/quintana roo/city/`;

let q = query(collection(db, refFirebase), where("places", "==", "ado")),
        data = await getDocs(q);
```

Intente con algo haci pero no me funciona

Answer (score -1):

Obtener campos especificos de un documento no es posible. Lo que puedes hacer es que una vez obtenido el query, puedes filtrar los documentos para que estos solo devuelvan el objeto `ado`.

```javascript
let refFirebase = `countries/mexico/state/quintana roo/city/`;

let q = query(collection(db, refFirebase), where("places", "==", "ado"));
let data = await getDocs(q);
let dataFilter = data.docs().map(document => ({ ado: document.ado }))
```

Espero que esto sea de ayuda.